# Multiple BEM elements and modifiers in Sass

Tags: sass, bem

I am using BEM with multiple elements and modifiers but different blocks.

```
.header__column--6
    width: 50%

.footer__column--6
    width: 50%
```

Is there a way to address the elements and modifiers globally in Sass? The following example results in an error.

```
*
    &__column--6
        width: 50%
```

Of course there would be the possibility to use global `grid__column--6` instead of naming each block individually.

However, in my project i am dependent on defining these different blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this attribute selector:

```
[class$='__column--6']
  width: 50%
```